# I just did a chmod -x chmod

Tags: linux, security, unix, freebsd

So I did a `chmod -x chmod`.  How I can fix this problem?  How do I give execute rights back to chmod?

Comment: You accidentally the whole `chmod`!

Comment: See also the [question on Unix & Linux SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/83862/21962).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In Linux:

```
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 /bin/chmod +x /bin/chmod
```

http://www.slideshare.net/cog/chmod-x-chmod

Comment: bindbn, I was about to post the same link :-) but I was reading myself as I am new to unix / linux stuff !!!

Comment: On a 64-bit distro, you may have to use `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` instead.  `ldd /bin/chmod` should list exactly which linker to run.

Comment: I would write a minimal program that uses chmod(2), but this is cooler

Comment: Could someone explain why that works, for the uninitiated? I think I get it, but some documentation would be great.

Comment: @Stefan: From `man ld-linux.so`: "ld.so [and ld-linux.so] loads the shared libraries needed by a program, prepares the program to run, and then runs it." (`ld.so` is for `a.out` format executables and `ld-linux.so` is for ELF format.)

Comment: @Stefan: The kernel doesn't really know how to load and execute dynamically-linked executables, because it is highly complex and follows the glibc, not the kernel. `ld-linux.so` is sort-of executable/library hybrid, sort-of statically linked, runs in userspace, and is responsible of loading dynamically-linked executables and all their dependencies, then running them.

Comment: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: symbolic link to `/lib32/ld-linux.so.2'
 What if I'm on 64bit machine?

Answer (score 18):

Use python:

```
# python
Python> import os
Python> os.chmod("/bin/chmod",0755)
```

Comment: And, as a one-liner: `python -c "import os; os.chmod('/bin/chmod', 0755)"`

Comment: @Thanatos `python -c '__import__("os").chmod("/bin/chmod", 0755)'` does the same without using any semicolons.

Answer (score 18):

This relies on the fact that permissions of a destination file are preserved rather than the source file when it is being copied over. We're "borrowing" the permissions of `ls`:

```
cp /bin/ls /tmp/chmod.tmp
cp /bin/chmod /tmp/chmod.tmp
mv /tmp/chmod.tmp /bin/chmod
```

Comment: I think your first `cp` needs to have the -p flag on

Comment: @Riking: It's not necessary for this purpose.

Comment: This was similar to the solution I came up with, but after `cp`ing the executable, I just `cat`'d the contents of `chmod` into the temp file.

Answer (score 10):

Using Perl:

```
% perl -e 'chmod 0755, qw[/bin/chmod]'
```

Answer (score 7):

`setfacl -m u::rx /bin/chmod`

... will grant the owner execute permissions.

But, the `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` trick is neat. :)

Answer (score 5):

This is weird... I saw something like this a few days ago via someone's tweet...

http://www.slideshare.net/cog/chmod-x-chmod

Comment: Links to other sites are not helpful as the link will become broken at some point.  This is like telling someone to google the answer.

Comment: @Phil Hannent: I've seen that slideshow too, just three days ago, so it was my first thought, if the OP was one of the applicants there.

Comment: Same, just saw this on Reddit a few days back...

Answer (score 5):

Should you be on a system where `/bin/chmod` can't be loaded by the dynamic linker:

```
# /bin/mv /bin/chmod /bin/chmod.tmp
# install -p -m 755 /bin/chmod.tmp /bin/chmod
```

This works on my MacOS X system.

Answer (score 2):

/rescue/chmod 555 /bin/chmod

I think you could also use mtree.

Comment: This would my favorite solution. It doesn't work with linux unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is not a real question: http://www.slideshare.net/cog/chmod-x-chmod

- Reinstall chown: sudo apt-get install --reinstall coreutils
- perl -e  'chmod 0755, "chmod"'
- more examples in the slides

Answer (score 1):

create a new chmod and use that for the original

```
umask 000
cat chmod > ~/my-chmod
~/my-chmod a+x chmod
```

Comment: Setting a umask of 000 won't give a file execute permission when it's created. It will, at best, get rw-rw-rw- permissions.

Comment: @Barry: It actually depends on the mode passed to creat(2)/open(2)/mkdir(2)/etc. If umask == 0 and the syscall that creates the file is given 0777 for the mode, then the file will have the execute bits turned on. For example, linkers/compilers pass 0777 when writing out an “executable file” (e.g. `(umask 000;gcc -o foo foo.c)` will produce a `foo` with mode 777). However, many (most?) shells pass 0666 when they open/create files for redirection, which means that this answer is not going to work under many shells.