# How do I restore access to sudo after chmod 750'ing /usr?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2

In a stroke of sheer brilliance, I just `chmod 750`'ed my `/usr` and `/etc` directory on my VPS. Now, whenever I run sudo, I get `-bash: sudo: command not found`. Is there *any* way you can think of for me to restore access?

I tried to `scp` sudo over to the computer, but got a

```
bash: /etc/bash.bashrc: Permission denied
bash: scp: command not found
lost connection
```

If you can figure this one out, you're a genius.

Comment: There are several possibilities in answers to [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/189627/i-just-did-a-chmod-x-chmod).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you get a console to the machine? If so, reboot into recovery mode or some such thing (add kernel opts init=/bin/sh will drop a root shell). Then you'll be root, and can chmod as needed.

Other options include doing a bare metal restore (you've got a backup, right?) (If you don't you might be able to cobble something together from whatever is in /bin)

Answer (score 3):

do `su root` instead of `sudo`

since `su` is often in `/bin`, you should not be impacted by your mistake

of course this requires you to know the root passwd...

Comment: Shoot, I don't know the root password. My user does have root privileges, though.

Comment: in that case i would just open up a support ticket and have someone at your vps provider fix the perms for you.

Answer (score 0):

Some VPS companies have web console access enabled. Check also that out.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use netcat to transfer sudo over?  At least on my Ubuntu (karmic) machine netcat is in /bin.

Unfortunately having the file won't help much since you'll need it to be setuid root for it to work and you won't have the permissions to make it so.